# How to return a Promise correct for chartjs

Tags: angular, firebase, charts, angularfire2

I have a service that call firebase, returns a promise. If firebase returns the data, they will be bound to a chartjs chart. But somehow I get an in Promise error.

So far I tried shifting around where to resolve the promise, but I always get the same error. When I print the returned array to the console, it looks perfect.

```
getChart()
  {
    let promise = new Promise((resolve, reject) => {

      let dates: string[] = [];
      let values: number[] = [];
      let response: any = [];

      let res: Observable<BodyFat[]> = this.db.list(this.BASE_PATH, ref => ref.orderByChild(this.DATE).limitToLast(40)).snapshotChanges()
    .pipe(map(items => {
      return items.map(item => {
        let bodyfat = new BodyFat;
        bodyfat.id = item.payload.key;
        bodyfat.date = new Date(item.payload.child(this.DATE).val());
        bodyfat.fat = item.payload.child(this.FAT).val();

        return bodyfat;
      })
    }));

    let i: number = 0;

    res.subscribe(data => {
      data.forEach(element => {

        i++;

        var shortDate = moment(element.date).format('DD.MM.YYYY');

        if(dates.indexOf(shortDate) === -1)
        {
          dates.push(shortDate);
          values.push(element.fat);
        }

        if(i === data.length-1)
        {
          response = {...}
        };

        resolve(response);
        }
      });
    });
    });

    return promise;
  }
```

```
    this.bodyfatService.getChart().then(function(data)
    {
      this.bodyFat = new Chart(document.getElementById('bodyFatChart'), data);
    });
```

At the moment I get the following error:  ERROR Error: Uncaught (in promise): TypeError: Cannot read property 'length' of null
TypeError: Cannot read property 'length' of null

But I expect the chart to be drawn. Maybe there is an easier way to plot firebase data in angular. Btw. static data works perfect.

Comment: Did you do `console.log(data)`?

Comment: Yes, and it looks perfect

Comment: Change it to `element.length-1`

Comment: gives me an error before compiling